# the loss suddenly was stuck to a very large value after having several epoch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions, gradient-descent, sigmoid-curve

When I changed the final activation layer in the same model from softmax to sigmoid in order to multilabel classification, the loss would suddenly get stuck at a very big value after several epoch. I have tried to use a small learning rate, but it does not work. When the loss went down at a certain value, the loss would promptly get to a very large value. The optimizer is Adam. Does anyone know what is going?[image]